# DKLang's StoreList and Virtual treeview's header text translation

Tags: delphi, internationalization, multilingual, virtualtreeview

So I use [the DKLang Localization Package](https://github.com/yktoo/dklang) for multi-language support.

`TDKLanguageController` has a property called `StoreList` (of type `TStrings`), where you can enter a `TMask`-compatible wildcard strings to **force** a property to be processed by DKLang, for example, `"*.SomeStringProp"` will force any component properties called `SomeStringProp` to be processed by DKLang.

The problem I'm having now is to force DKlang to handle Virtual treeview's header captions, ie. `TVirtualStringTree.Header.Columns[i].Text`.

I've tried `"*.Text"`, `"Header.Columns.Text"` and `"Header.Columns*.Text"`, none of them worked.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can declare constant for each column text:

```
myVirtualStringTree.Header.Columns[0].Text := myConstant1;
myVirtualStringTree.Header.Columns[1].Text := myConstant2;
myVirtualStringTree.Header.Columns[2].Text := myConstant3;
```

and manage those constants with the DKLang editor by the "user defined constants".

Comment: Thanks, but I have a lot of such virtual treeview instances so it'll require a lot of work, I'd prefer the automated approach, if possible.